# Garbage Collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I found this question in one of the Java dumps and I would like to know how many object would be available after `more code here 11` comment in the following code

```
public class Tahiti {
    Tahiti t;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tahiti t = new Tahiti();
        Tahiti t2 = t.go(t);
        t2 = null;
        // more code here 11
    }
    Tahiti go(Tahiti t) {
        Tahiti t1 = new Tahiti();
        Tahiti t2 = new Tahiti();
        t1.t = t2;
        t2.t = t1;
        t.t = t2;
        return t1;
    }
}
```

My answer was one since the object reference by `t2` object under main method has been set to null and because of that there isnt any reference pointing to that object but i found out that answer is 0

Could anyone help me on this? thanks

Comment: You can't predict when garbage collection will occur.

Comment: @KevinBowersox This is not about predicting when GC will occur. It is about the *reachability* of objects (or if you prefer, its opposite---*availability for collection*).

Comment: Looks like all created references are reachable through `t`.

Comment: @Bart could you tell me how ??

Comment: `t1` and `t2` have a circular reference to each other. `t2` is assigned to `t.t`. Now all references are reachable through `t`.

Answer (score 3):

> How many objects are available?

All three. Variable `t` in main points directly to the first. That object's `t` field points at a second object, which was known as `t2` within the `go` method. That object's `t` field points at the third object, known as `t1` within the `go` method.

Proof:

```
System.out.println(t);
System.out.println(t.t);
System.out.println(t.t.t);
```

Assuming the VM manages to give all three created objects unique hashcodes (which it generally should), you should see something like:

```
Tahiti@107ebe1
Tahiti@10f11b8
Tahiti@544ec1
```

You could give the objects a `String name;` field to make distinguishing them easier.

Comment: i am a bit confused could you please be more clear on That object's t field points at the third object, known as t1 within the go method comment of yours, thanks.